# Unexpected brush filtering behaviour

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I recently started learning D3.js, Crossfilter, and Dc.js, and am butting heads against a problem I am out of my depth solving.

I have two line graphs, one representing an overview of all data, and the other representing a more granular, zoomed-in version of interval created by brushing the overview. Both line graphs are rendered covering the same interval (see below).

[image: Initial view]

The top graph is set to the following options:

```
.dimension(CRS.dimensions.hourly)
.group(CRS.groups.hourly)
```

and the bottom:

```
.dimension(CRS.dimensions.daily)
.group(CRS.groups.daily)
```

The relevant initialisations are

```
dimensions.hourly = crs.dimension(function(d){ return d.dd })
dimensions.daily = crs.dimension(function(d){ return d3.time.day(d.dd) })

groups.hourly: dimensions.hourly.group().reduce(
        function(p,v) {
            p.imps += v.imps
            p.clicks += v.clicks
            p.conversions += v.conversions
            p.cost += v.cost

            return p
        },
        function(p,v) {
            p.imps -= v.imps
            p.clicks -= v.clicks
            p.conversions -= v.conversions
            p.cost -= v.cost

            return p
        },
        function() {
            return {
                imps:0,
                clicks:0,
                conversions:0,
                cost:0
            }
        }
    ),
    groups.daily: dimensions.daily.group().order(function(d){return d}).reduce(
        function(p,v) {
            p.imps += v.imps
            p.clicks += v.clicks
            p.conversions += v.conversions
            p.cost += v.cost

            return p
        },
        function(p,v) {
            p.imps -= v.imps
            p.clicks -= v.clicks
            p.conversions -= v.conversions
            p.cost -= v.cost

            return p
        },
        function() {
            return {
                imps:0,
                clicks:0,
                conversions:0,
                cost:0
            }
        }
    )
```

Ideally, the bottom graph would not change when brushed, but this is not the case. When I brush the bottom graph, it is automatically updated to have all values set to 0 outside of the selected interval, which is undesired:

[image: Brushed view]

Clicking outside of the interval resets the top graph (as it should), but the bottom graph does not change:

[image: Post-brushed view]

I have attempted several solutions to make the bottom graph immutable, including changing `groups.daily` to a `reduceSum`, to no avail. I assume the problem lies with how I'm handling dimensions, but I have been unable so far to get the desired result.

If someone could point me in the right direction, that'd be fantastic! Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you've wired the brush select up to filter the data in your top graph by filtering domain content of the lower graph, but then you're setting the data of the lower graph to that filtered array.

Comment: @BenLesh, I see. That'd make sense given that the dimensions of both the top and bottom graph are hooked up to the same initial object property (d.dd). How can I set the lower graph so that its data won't change, or that it won't be filtered on brushing?

Comment: Sorry, I wish I could help more, but I'm not really an expert on Crossfilter. If it's a matter of handling some brush event, then updating the data in the upper graph manually, I'd say make sure that the code your using is *only* setting .data() on the upper graph to some new filter()'ed or splice()'ed array. I hope that helps.

Comment: The intended behavior of crossfilter is that each dimension will filter the other dimensions but (of course) not itself. Assuming you want each chart to filter the other, it looks like you have the right definitions but perhaps your dimensions and groups are not matching in your charts? Please take another look at the `.group()` and `.dimension()` initializations of your charts.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resorting to the `.on("preRedraw")` listener as follows:

```
.on("preRedraw", function(){
    CRS.dimension.hourly.filterAll();
})
```

I am unsure if this is the best solution, but it seems to do the trick!